# Can I publish an android app, that uses the maps SDK, without setting up a google maps platform billing account?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

Google decided to change the pricing and billing methods when you use one of their APIS's eg. Google maps SDK for android. Now you can't get a key without setting up a credit card account, I know that sucks. Fortunately I got a key before all of this happened. My question is:
Can I publish an app, that uses the maps api, into the play store without setting up a billing account?.

You can see the new billing and pricing changes here:
https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/

Comment: I'm not submitting an answer, since it's only speculation, I haven't tried it myself. My guess is that yes you can still publish your app. However, [here](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/user-guide/pricing-changes/) they specify that "If you choose not to add a billing account, there is a risk that if your usage exceeds $200 in a given month, your Maps API implementation will be degraded or other API requests will return an error."

Comment: @TheWanderingMind thanks man. I don't think I am going to consume more than $200